# Objective-C properties are not being recognized in header file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wonder if I'm doing something completely stupid here... I'm clearly missing something. I've gotten used to the pattern of defining properties of a custom class, however I seem to be hitting a point where extended classes do not recognize new properties. Case of point, here's my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

@interface MyRootController : MyTableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *sectionList;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sectionList;
@end
```

Now, for some reason that "sectionList" property is not turning green within my interface file (ie: it's not being recognized as custom property it seems). As a result, I'm getting all kinds of errors down in my implementation. The first is right at the top of my implementation where I try to synthesize the property:

```
#import "MyRootController.h"

@implementation MyRootController
@synthesize sectionList;
```

That synthesize line throws the error "No declaration of property 'sectionList' found in the interface". So, this is really confusing. I'm clearly doing something wrong, although I can't put my finger on what.

One thought: I am extending another custom class of my own. Do I need to specify some kind of super-class declaration to keep the architecture from getting sealed one level up?

Comment: Everything looks OK on first glance... are you importing `NSMutableArray` as well?

Comment: Do you need to explicitly import NSMutableArray? I thought it came in with UIKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drat, it was a pathing issue. I still haven't figured out quite how XCode decides what folder to place new files into... and when two joined files end up in different folders, things don't work. Thanks for the reply, fbrereto.